# Error when launching RespondCMS

Tags: respondcms

I recently made a fresh install of Debian 8 + Apache + MySql on a VPS to host RespondCMS.

The installation went well but when I launch the application in a browser, a part of the layout is broken and the themes are not listed.

[Layout is broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTZeH.png)

When I open the debug console in Chrome, I can see that's it's linked to an error loading a resource (api/theme).

[api/theme error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eM73v.png)

Did I forget something or is it a bug in the app ?

Answer (score 0):

I came across a post mentioning a page at test/index.php which lists all the requirements of the app that are not matched.

Fixing them one by one, I finally fixed my original issue when enabling mod_rewrite module of Apache and adding a "Directory" tag in the .conf file of the website (AllowOverride None).

Hope it will help ;)